# How to remove index.php in codeigniter on ubuntu server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have researched on all the question on stackoverflow to remove index.php from codeigniter but still i am unable to do it. Only landing page opens but rest of the pages are blank. 
I m using own `ubuntu` linux server.
My rewrite module is also on. I tried `$config['uri_protocol']` with all possible values. `AUTO, PATH_INFO, QUERY_STRING, ORIG_PATH_INFO`.
My htaccess code is here

```
RewriteEngine on
AddType text/x-component .htc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

vhost file is here

```
DocumentRoot /home/black-sheep/black-sheep.org

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride FileInfo
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/black-sheep/black-sheep.org/>
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

My website url is

```
http://black-sheep.org/
```

This is the path  when i echo `__FILE__` on  index.php

```
/home/black-sheep/black-sheep.org/index.php
```

Its amazing that wordpress site on same server without index.php is running good with following htaccess.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried with this htaccess also but it doesn't work for me.

Please suggest me the solution. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled ?

Comment: yes it is.. and i m sure..

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem. And I fix it.
You must add .htaccess file in root directory of your site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**And main** you must change site conf in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.
 Search *Directory /var/www/*
Change **AllowOverride None** -> **AllowOverride All**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Your solution makes the output Error 500

Answer (score 2):

```
    How to remove index.php in localhost(Ubantu) using codeigniter

   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    write this code below.

   <Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
  </Directory>

  within codeigniter framework config/config.php
  In application/config/config.php change:

 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
 to:
 $config['index_page'] = '';

 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/code_test';

 make .htaccess file main folder directory

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

Paste this below code into .htaccess file and move it to you codeigniter folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: what is the value you have added on $config['index_page'] on config.php

Comment: It is CI default AUTO

Comment: can you make it as   $config['index_page'] == '' ; Let me know if still problem exists

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but able to correct it. I am giving you the full instruction. follow step by step..

First check whether mod_rewrite is on or not from Terminal by typing the below command :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then open file `apache2.conf` which is located in the below mentioned directory

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find `<Directory /var/www/>` in the file and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

If it is not allowing you to save the file, that means the directory don't have the required permission. so please give that by running the below command.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/apache2/` and then save the file.

Now write your `.htaccess` file and save the file by placing the below codes.

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`

Then restart your apache service once by the below command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hopefully, then it will work...